# In Linux, how to get the man page for compiled programs?

Tags: linux, aptitude, compile, man

I know that installing a package through APT (apt-get or aptitude for my computer) will automatically install the appropriate man pages and update the man database. When I want to build the same packages, however, no man page is installed and I cannot use man for that program. How do I get the man pages for software I have compiled? (I am running Ubuntu 10.10).

Comment: Are you trying to build a `deb` package, or are you compiling then installing with `make install`? If the former, post your `debian/rules`. If the latter, explain how you configure the program (did you run `./configure`, did you edit the makefile, what variables did you pass to `make`, etc.).

Comment: I used cmake to configure the program; the command line was `cmake ../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local`. I then ran `make && sudo make install` as usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you configuring your software build with the default locations (in /usr) and installing as root?  (but not building as root i hope).  If so, then the man pages, if there are any, should be installed where `man` can already see them.

If you are installing to a nonstandard location, you need to let `man` know where they are.  You can use the `MANPATH` environment variable to do this.  Set it to the normal `man` directories, and add your install dir to it as well.  Something like `export MANPATH=/usr/share/man:/path/to/your/dir`

**EDIT**: Also, I am not sure about the 'man database'.  There really isn't one.  There are some distributions that do post processing of the man pages, either compress it, or uncompress it.  But they don't really keep a list of man pages anywhere. In pseudo code:

```
for DIR in $MANPATH
    for SEC in $MANSECTIONS (or just the one section if you give as `-s SEC`)
        open dirlist for $DIR/man${SEC}
        in dir list list, look for $COMMAND.$SEC
        if you find it, display and exit
```

This may be your issue.  If you installed to a non-standard dir, is the naming convention right? If you have a file bubba.1, then the file should be installed into some path `/path/to/bubba/install/man1/bubba.1` and `MANPATH=/usr/share/man:/path/to/bubba/install`

Comment: I sometimes configure my software to compile in /usr/local, that could be the problem. I am not compiling as root, but I am installing as root (make; sudo make install). However, I don't think that the man pages are there (I looked in the man8 folder).

Comment: Also, if there is no 'database', how come there are folders for man-db and there is a program called 'mandb'?

Comment: @AniDev: i have no mandb on my system.  For my above comment, I ran strace on my man command to see if it hit a db, it did not.  I can not say for all versions of man whether or not they use one.

Comment: OK, thanks. Whenever APT installs a package, it almost always says at the end somewhere 'Processing triggers for man-db...'.

Comment: Does not quite answer my question, but helpful nonetheless, so I am marking your answer as my accepted answer.